# Como usar as funções tbl_svysummary e add_difference para comparar dois grupos cujas variaveis de um objeto survey foram filtradas no subset

Tags: r, tidyverse

Estou tentando fazer uma operação cujo reprodução pode ser feita pelo código abaixo. A ideia é comparar dois grupos de um survey usando a função `add_difference` do pacote `gtsummary`. A função dá a diferença e o p-valor ao mesmo tempo. Mas, estou obtendo o erro `` Error: 'tbl_summary'/'tbl_svysummary' object must have a `by=` value with exactly two levels ``. Alguém saberia como resolver?

```
library(PNSIBGE)
library(tidyverse) 
library(gtsummary)
pns <- get_pns(year = 2019, labels = T) 
pns.2 <- subset(pns, C009 %in% c("Branca", "Preta"))
pns.2$variables$C009 <- droplevels(pns.2$variables$C009) 
pns.2 %>% tbl_svysummary(by = C009, include = c(C006)) %>% 
  add_difference()
```

O ponto é que, usando esse mesmo esquema, ele funcionou num exemplo genérico.

```
library(survey)
data(api)
svy <- survey::svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) 
svy <- subset(svy, stype %in% c("E", "H"))
svy$variables$stype <- droplevels(svy$variables$stype)
svy %>%
  tbl_svysummary(by = stype, include = c(api00, stype)) %>% 
    add_difference()
```

Não encontrei qual pode ser o problema no primeiro exemplo. Alguma dica?